# How to dynamically create variables and combine it to the dataframe in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply, k-means

I am running `kmeans` for multiple `number of clusters` and then trying to **combine**  `cluster results` to the `original dataframe`.

from post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10838/produce-a-list-of-variable-name-in-a-for-loop-then-assign-values-to-the I am using their below mentioned code to **create variables dynamically** and modifying as per my need.

original code in the above post:

```
x <- as.list(rnorm(10000))
names(x) <- paste("a", 1:length(x), sep = "")
list2env(x , envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Now applying this on **iris** data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(factoextra)
```

this works fine in creating 3 list of clusters:

```
# running for 1 to 3 clusters
lapply(1:3,

function(cluster_num){
  cluster_res_list <- as.list(kmeans(iris %>% select(-Species), cluster_num, nstart = 25)) 
  names(cluster_res_list) <- paste("iris_clus", 1:length(cluster_res_list), sep="_")
  list2env(cluster_res_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
 
 # iris_df <- cbind(iris, cluster_res_list)
} )
```

**Issue:** When I try to combine them with the original dataset I am getting an error: `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : cannot coerce class ‘"kmeans"’ to a data.frame`

```
lapply(1:3,

function(cluster_num){
  cluster_res_list <- as.list(kmeans(iris %>% select(-Species), cluster_num, nstart = 25)) 
  names(cluster_res_list) <- paste("iris_clus", 1:length(cluster_res_list), sep="_")
  list2env(cluster_res_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
 
  # to combine each cluster result to original df
  iris_df <- cbind(iris, cluster_res_list)
} )
```

Comment: The `broom` package offers some functions that translate model outputs into tidy data frames. Example: `kmeans(iris %>% select(-Species), 3, nstart = 25) %>% broom::tidy()`. I'm not sure what kind of data frame you need but I hope this helps.

Comment: @Damian I just want to combine the results of kmeans clusters to the original dataframe. I have tried `iris_df <- cbind(iris, paste0("iris_clus_", cluster_num))` as well but this didn't work either. will surely check broom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from `kmeans` can be viewed as a matrix using the `fitted` function. The row names of the matrix identify the clusters. If you want to add a column to the original date frame that identifies the cluster assignment, then something like this would work.

Using 3 clusters as an example:

```
cluster_num <- 3

iris %>% 
    select(-Species) %>% 
    kmeans(centers = cluster_num, nstart = 25) %>% 
    fitted() %>% 
    row.names() %>%
    tibble(iris_clus = .) %>%
    cbind(iris) %>% 
    tail()

    iris_clus Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
145         2          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
146         2          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
147         1          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
148         2          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
149         2          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150         1          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```

Inserting this into the `lapply` from your example

```
lapply(1:3, function(cluster_num) {
    iris %>% 
        select(-Species) %>% 
        kmeans(centers = cluster_num, nstart = 25) %>% 
        fitted() %>% 
        row.names() %>%
        tibble(iris_clus = .) %>%
        cbind(iris) 
})
```

Here's one way to combine it all into one data set. With one column per model

```
clusters <- Reduce(cbind, lapply(1:3, function(cluster_num) {

   result <- iris %>% 
        select(-Species) %>% 
        kmeans(centers = cluster_num, nstart = 25) %>% 
        fitted() %>% 
        row.names() %>% 
        tibble(iris_clus = .)

   names(result) <- paste("iris_clus", cluster_num, sep = "_")
   return(result)

}))

cbind(iris, clusters)
```

Comment: Yes this is getting me the cluster result in the dataframe but not for all 3 runs of cluster results. So for that I tried `tibble(paste("iris_clus", cluster_num, sep = "_") = .) %>%
        cbind(iris)` but that is not working.

Comment: Also tried this code but this is also giving error: 

`iris_df <- iris

lapply(1:3, function(cluster_num) {
    iris %>% 
        select(-Species) %>% 
        kmeans(centers = cluster_num, nstart = 25) %>% 
        fitted() %>% 
        row.names() %>%
        # tibble(iris_clus = .) %>%
        tibble(paste0("iris_clus_", cluster_num) = .) %>%
        cbind(iris_df)
})`

Comment: What would the desired output look like? Would there be a total of 3 new columns added to the iris data set in the final output?

Comment: Yes, `iris_clus_1`, `iris_clus_2`, `iris_clus_3` columns should be added to the iris data. Thats why I am running it with `apply` function so that **result** of all the **kmeans cluster** trials gets combined to the original data.

Comment: The `lapply` function stores each result separately and returns them as a list. The list of outputs can be combined after it runs. That said, using a `for` loop instead that updates the same data frame with new columns each time might be more consistent with what you have in mind.

Comment: Updated the post with an example building on the `lapply`

Comment: Thanks alot @Damian for sharing multiple examples & explainations. I was having trouble in naming `dynamic variable` in both `apply` & `for-loop` methods. This code from your example`names(result) <- paste("iris_clus", cluster_num, sep = "_")` solves the issue for me in both `apply` & `for-loop`. Thanks again :)